# Como colocar texto em negrito em String.xml do Android?

Tags: android

Olá!

No Android, eu coloquei:

```
<string name="msg"> <b> Mensagem: </b> A mensagem que será ixibida junto ao áudio na tela. </string>
```

Justo onde está escrito "Mensagem" eu gostaria que estivesse em negrito, porém, mesmo usando a tag de bold não está funcionando.

Podem me ajudar, por favor ?

Comment: Coloque a tag <html> no inicio e feche ela </html> no final da String e veja se funciona

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade usar apenas o `<b> </br>` funcionou. O problema era que eu fiquei a semana inteira desenvolvendo o app no meu note que é ruim e eu não conseguia testar. Agora já em casa eu testei no meu PC e funcionou o negrito, porém só não aparece dentro do Android Studio, apenas na hora da execução da aplicação :)