# TextView - Deixar apenas uma palavra em bold

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, textview

Tenho um `TextView` que mostra o seguinte texto na tela:

---

Como esta:

valor:
PROMOÇÃO!

---

Como quero:

valor:
**PROMOÇÃO!**

---

Tem como  **colocar bold em apenas uma palavra do `TextView`**? Ou seja, tem como eu fazer isso sem precisar criar 2 `TextView`, um com *bold*, um sem *bold*.

Gostaria de usar apenas um.

---

## Código:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Valor:\nPROMOÇÃO!"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#42a56b" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android:text="@string/promotion"

<string name="promotion">valor:<br /><b>PROMOÇÃO!</b></string>
```

Comment: Ele trouxe a informação na tela, mas não migrou para bold na palavra.

Comment: veja se ajuda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371092/how-to-make-a-specific-text-on-textview-bold

Comment: veja se a resposta dessa pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94795/como-colocar-texto-em-negrito-em-string-xml-do-android  não é o seu caso.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, acho que não tem como mudar o estilo de só uma palavra dentro do text view. Quando você setar a propriedade ele vai colocar todo o texto do componente neste formato.

Você não poderia simplesmente usar dois ou três TextViews? Ou seja, você separaria a parte do texto que deseja colocar como negrito em um TextView separado, com esta propriedade setada.

Comment: O AP explicitamente diz que quer uma alternativa a usar mais de um TextView.